# Spring Data - MongoDB - Aggregation how to project all fields of grouped reference document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have 2 documents, Topic and comment. Each topic has many comments and the documents look like this:

```
@Document
public class Topic {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String title;
}


@Document
public class Comment {

    @NotBlank
    private String text;

    @Indexed
    @NotBlank
    private String topic;  // id of topic

    @CreatedDate
    @Indexed
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
}
```

So I actually save the id reference of Topic within comments.

This is my aggregation scenario: **List the topics, which received most comments today**. So three things:

- Get all comments of today (MatchOperation)
- Group by topic and sum comments (GroupOperation)
- Sort by this sum (SortOperation)

This is the code so far:

```
MatchOperation filterCreatedDate = match(Criteria.where("createdDate").gte(today.atStartOfDay()).lt(today.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()));
GroupOperation groupByTopic = group("topic").count().as("todaysCommentsCount");
SortOperation sortByTodaysCommentsCount = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "todaysCommentsCount");

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterCreatedDate, groupByTopic, sortByTodaysCommentsCount);
AggregationResults<TopTopic> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, TopTopic.class);
```

This is a special Class for this output:

```
public class TopTopic {
    private int todaysCommentsCount;
}
```

And this is the output of my aggregation where there is only one topic:

```
{
    "mappedResults": [
        {
            "todaysCommentsCount": 3
        }
    ],
    "rawResults": {
        "results": [
            {
                "_id": "5dbdca8112a617031728c417",     // topic id
                "todaysCommentsCount": 3
            }
        ],
        "ok": 1.0
    },
    "serverUsed": null,
    "uniqueMappedResult": {
        "todaysCommentsCount": 1
    }
}
```

I thought I am actually pretty close, but somehow it works only when I have only one topic. When there are comments from more than one topic which should then create multiple groups, I get this error:

```
Could not write JSON: Expected unique result or null, but got more than one!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Expected unique result or null, but got more than one! (through reference chain: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationResults[\"uniqueMappedResult\"]
```

.. althought i do not call any getUniqueMappedResult method.

What do I do wrong?

Secondly, how can I get rid of my output class TopTopic, and instead return the original Topic values extended with todaysCommentsCount, without creating a special output class?

I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Part**

You are sending the `AggregationResults` back to caller where jackson is serializing into json and failing when it is calling `getUniqueMappedResult`.

Add the topic field _id to `TopTopic` and read mapped results in `AggregationResults`.

```
List<TopTopic> topTopics = result.getMappedResults()
```

Your output would look like

```
 [
    {
       "_id": "5dbdca8112a617031728c417",
       "todaysCommentsCount": 3
    }
 ]
```

**Second Part**

You can use `$$ROOT` variable with `$first` to map the entire document in the `$group` stage followed by `$replaceRoot` to promote the merge document ( `$mergeObjects` to merge the `doc` and `todaysCommentCount` ).

Add the `todaysCommentsCount` to Topic class.

Something like

```
MatchOperation filterCreatedDate = match(Criteria.where("createdDate").gte(today.atStartOfDay()).lt(today.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()));
GroupOperation groupByTopic = group("topic").first("$$ROOT").as("doc").count().as("todaysCommentsCount");
SortOperation sortByTodaysCommentsCount = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "todaysCommentsCount");
ReplaceRootOperation replaceRoot = Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ObjectOperators.valueOf("doc").mergeWith(new Document("todaysCommentsCount", "$todaysCommentsCount")));

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterCreatedDate, groupByTopic, sortByTodaysCommentsCount, replaceRoot);
AggregationResults<TopTopic> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, Topic.class);

List<Topic> topTopics = result.getMappedResults();
```

Your output would look like

```
 [
    {
       "_id": "5dbdca8112a617031728c417",
       "title" : "topic",
       "todaysCommentsCount": 3
    }
 ]
```

**Update** ( Add $lookup stage to pull in topic fields)

```
MatchOperation filterCreatedDate = match(Criteria.where("createdDate").gte(today.atStartOfDay()).lt(today.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()));
GroupOperation groupByTopic = group("topic").count().as("todaysCommentsCount");
SortOperation sortByTodaysCommentsCount = sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "todaysCommentsCount");
LookupOperation lookupOperation = LookupOperation.newLookup().
                                    from("topic").
                                    localField("_id").
                                    foreignField("_id").
                                    as("topic");
ReplaceRootOperation replaceRoot = Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ObjectOperators.valueOf("todaysCommentsCount").mergeWithValuesOf(ArrayOperators.arrayOf("topic").elementAt(0)));

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(filterCreatedDate, groupByTopic, sortByTodaysCommentsCount, lookupOperation, replaceRoot);
AggregationResults<TopTopic> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Comment.class, Topic.class);

List<Topic> topTopics = result.getMappedResults();
```

Comment: thank you!  do you think this way which you described with $$ROOT and merging is a bit performance killer for a noQsl database?  My application should run this query very very often. Do you think that I should take also the text of topics within the comment document, and use only the comment document for the entire application?  because other than the title (which has max 100 chars), I do not have anything else in topic document.. And I really do not have any case on my user interface where the topic titles are shown alone..

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry, I didn't realize you want topic fields in the output. In my answer $$ROOT is mapping other comment fields (text ...) which you lose when you group by id. For fetching topic fields you would need to use $lookup. It would make sense to store the topics text with comment for faster reads.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and I've resolved it by calling the `getMappedResults()`. I have a function `AggregationResults<?> doSomeAggreagation();` in the repository. When you want the result of the function you should call it as
`doSomeAggreagation().getMappedResults()`